How to not trigger the buttons when dragging finger out of it
I know that this is a very basic things in UI, but I was not able to find any help in the internet.
I am making my own UI library for love2d that was made for mobile touch screen and when I made the buttons I had this issue with my release function which is when I press the button and then drag my finger out it gets triggered as if a lifted my finger off, which is not wanted.
The code:
for i, v in pairs(DPAD.isDown) do

    DPAD.isReleassed[i] = false

    if v then

      wasTouch[i] = true

    end

    if not v and wasTouch[i] then

      DPAD.isReleassed[i] = true

      wasTouch[i] = false

    end

  end

What it does is it uses the DPAD.isDown function which checks if you are hovering the button if it's true it it saves that and if you are not touching anymore DPAD.released is triggered
But by doing that the program can't differentiate between dragging out from the button and lifting the finger out of it
I thought of a bunch of stuff I have not tried them because I judged them to be over complected and I knew there was a much simpler way to do it and after some googling I had no real solution

I was able to figure it out myself and the solution was pretty simple as I expected
for i, v in pairs(DPAD.isDown) do
    DPAD.isReleassed[i] = false

    if v and #touches == lastTouches + 1   then -- check if you pressed it or dragged it in
      wasPressed[i] = true
    end
    if not v and wasPressed[i] then
      if #touches == lastTouches - 1 then -- check if you lifted or dragged it out
        DPAD.isReleassed[i] = true
      end
      wasPressed[i] = false
    end
  end
  lastTouches = #touches

What I did is I saved the number of current touches #touches in a new variable called lastTouches and that allows me to compare the number of current touches with the number of touches in the last frame.
And when you stop touching if it went down by 1 this means that you lifted it and if it's the same this means that it was dragged out.
Also I checke if when you touch the button for the first time if you dragged the finger into it or you directly pressed it that way when you drag it out and come back it doesn't trigger.
